# SQL Calculate week number from a date column

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the following database schema
Facts(ReportNo, ReportName, Load_Date)

**Load_Date** is a column of (**number** type) and has
records of date in YYYYMMDD Format.

I need to print the week number for each row using the already existing dates
in Load_Date. Since it is already of type **number**, I do not have to convert it from date to char.

Output should be
**Week Number | ReportNo | ReportName

Comment: Please define 'week number' - ISO week-of-year?  week-of-year (every 7 days since January 1st)?  Week of month?  Or something else?  Also, please note that storing dates in a number format is asking for trouble - you're giving up the built-in validity checking, never mind the fact that date/time don't really work that way.  In fact, any 'week number' calculation other than 'week of month' (based on days since start of month) will _require_ you to translate to a `date` type, unless you want to do some absolutely insane math to figure it out yourself (the next value after 20130228 is 20130301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
select ReportNo,ReportName,to_char(to_date(Load_Date,'yyyymmdd'),'ww') from Facts
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the result of to_char(<date>, 'ww') is locale dependent.